# Returning multiple matching values from multiple columns - Excel 2016

Tags: excel

I have a work schedule that lists codes for reports to be worked on each day, with dates listed in column A and hours of the day listed in Row 1 - similar to below but running out to over a year:

```
            | 0900 | 1000 | 1100 | 1200 | 1300 | 1400 | 1500 | 1600 | 
 25/03/2019 | C01  | C01  | C02  | C02  | C02  | C02  | C02  | C02  |
 26/03/2019 | C02  | C02  | C02  | C03  | C03  | C03  | C03  | C03  |
 27/03/2019 | C04  | C04  | C04  | C04  | C04  | C04  | C04  | C04  |
 28/03/2019 | C05  | C05  | P12  | P12  | P12  | P12  | P12  | P12  |
 29/03/2019 | P12  | P12  | P12  | P12  | P12  | P12  | P12  | P12  |
```

I need to be able to pull a list of all reports being worked on in a particular week into a column - ideally referencing a cell that lists the first day of the week. For the above I'd want to see something like:

```
 25/03/2019
 C01
 C02
 C03
 C04
 C05
 P12
```

I've tried various iterations of INDEX and MATCH and haven't been able to get anywhere as the data is spread across a matrix. Ideally I would rather not use VBA but don't seem to be having any luck with native Excel functions.

I'd appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried already?

Comment: Thanks Pedro - I've tried an index match array formula but I've only been able to pull back the first result (in the 0900 slot).

Answer (score 0):

Base on the look for your example you can try just copy and paste with transpose.

```
Copy your Dataset
Right click and "Paste Special"
Check "Transpose"
```

let me know if this is the way you wanted.

If this is an dynamic list with larger set I would recommend an user-define function.

Comment: Hiya - that won't do unfortunately! The matrix I listed is just a sample from the larger set and the dates go out for over a year, not just a week. The data is also regularly being updated so doing it this manual way isn't practical.